# Combining Band Data

Tags: arcgis-pro, landsat-8, combine, landsat-5, earth-explorer

I recently downloaded Landsat 8 and 5 imagery from Earth Explorer, but my problem is that all of my data bands are separate and not composite. Does anyone have any advice for getting them to combine to create a cohesive image so I can get better NIR and NDVI data for my project? I've tried redownloading the same data a second time but it doesn't seem to want to work with me. Any advice?

Using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.3

Comment: Please edit your question to specify what software you use.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, Composite Bands was the function I was looking for.